# Stop Propagation not working Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi guys when i enter one of my div i should indicate it with making its border black but even if i use stoppropagation it add border all parent divs. Is there any way to make my hover just for child div? My divs are changing its position when i add border??

```js
$('div').hover(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();

});

function run() {

  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.backgroundColor = "green"; //create new div
  div.style.height = "100%";
  div.style.width = "50%";
  div.style.left = "0.1%";
  div.addEventListener("click", run); //bind click to new div
  this.appendChild(div);

  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.backgroundColor = "red"; //create new div
  div.style.height = "100%";
  div.style.position = "relative";
  div.style.height = "100%";
  div.style.width = "49.8%";
  div.style.left = "50.1%";
  div.style.top = "-100%";


  div.addEventListener("click", run); //bind click to new div
  this.appendChild(div);

  this.removeEventListener("click", run); //remove the original click event

}
document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", run); //bind the initial click event
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
div#start {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
}
div:hover {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="start" width='400px' height='30px'></div>
```

Comment: `stopPropagation` only affects Javascript handlers, not the CSS `:hover` selector.

Comment: When you add 1px border to your divs their position will be changed because their width and height have been changed.

Comment: Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments, https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/ only affects the event itself, no interaction with css.

> **event.stopPropagation()**
>
> Returns:
>
> Description: Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Handlers being event handlers, such as https://api.jquery.com/hover/, not to be confused with css psuedo-code like `':hover', ':link', ':active'`, ect (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp)

Look instead at rethinking your css and making use of greater specifity or even the '!important' suffix on a rule to stop it being overriden.

Also, use of the jquery $.hover (https://api.jquery.com/hover/) can be useful for applying classes dynamically that require no complex mapping of css.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do anything with javascript. All that is needed is CSS.

just add a `:hover` selector to the divs you want to change border on. Since all parent divs are also hovered at the same time, you need to make a selector that doesn't affect those divs. Add a class like `hover-sensitive` to the div you want to set border on, and use that in your selector

```
div.hover-sensitive:hover {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

**Update:**

To not make the border move the div around, use the css attribute `outline` instead of `border`. Its syntax is the same as for border.